# Awodey's Category Theory Example 3.6. co-product of Top

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, coproduct

I'm having problems with Example 3.6 of Awodey's Category Theory Book: In Top, the coproduct of two spaces $X+Y$ is their disjoint union with the topology $ O(X+Y) \cong O(X) × O(Y) $.

But I don't understand why $ O(X+Y) \cong O(X) × O(Y) $ holds true.

Looking at the site below([see atatched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLWHl.png)), I think $ O(X+Y) \cong O(X) + O(Y) $ is correct.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coproduct

I appreciate it if someone here can help me.

Comment: An open subset of the disjoint union $X + Y$ is the disjoint union of two open subsets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. You need both an open subset of $X$ _and_ one of $Y$, so that there is a canonical bijection $O(X+Y) \simeq O(X) \times O(Y)$.

Answer (score 3):

The topology on the disjoint union is
$$O(X+Y) = \{U \subset X + Y \mid U \cap X \in O(X), U \cap Y \in O(Y) \} .$$A bit more abstract, let $\mathfrak P(S)$ denotes the power set of $S$. We define functions
$$\phi : \mathfrak P(X+Y) \to  \mathfrak P(X) \times \mathfrak P(Y), \phi(C) = (C \cap X, C \cap Y) ,$$
$$\psi : \mathfrak P(X) \times \mathfrak P(Y) \to \mathfrak P(X+Y) , \phi(A,B) = A + B .$$
Then $\psi \circ \phi = id$ and $\phi \circ \psi = id$, i.e. $\phi$ and $\psi$ are bijections which are inverse to each other.

We have
$$O(X+Y) = \phi^{-1}(O(X) \times O(Y)) .$$
In other words, $\phi$ restricts to a bijection
$$\Phi : O(X+Y) \to O(X) \times O(Y) .$$
This is the meaning of
$$ O(X+Y) \cong O(X) × O(Y) \tag{1} .$$
Note that we do not have $ O(X+Y) = O(X) × O(Y) $.  Formula $(1)$ only says that there is a canonical bijection between the sets on the LHS and RHS.

It is not true that $ O(X+Y) \cong O(X) + O(Y)$. This would mean that the open subsets of $X+Y$ are either open subsets of $X$ are open subsets of $Y$. No set of the form $A + B$ with $A \ne \emptyset$ and $B \ne \emptyset$ would be open. In other words,  $O(X) + O(Y)$ is not closed under union.